# How to execute same php codes in two different elements with different results locating on the same page

Tags: php, html

I have a php code below that is placed in under two different select elements on the same html page.

**HTML**

```
<select id="multiclient" class="form-control custom-select" name="multiclient">
  <?php
    include 'sql/load-account.php';
  ?>
</select>

<select id="client" class="form-control custom-select" name="client">
  <?php
    include 'sql/load-account.php';
  ?>
</select>
```

**load-account.php**

```
$account = '<option value="MultiClient" selected disabled hidden>MultiClient</option>'."\n";
$a_list = $DB_CON_C->query("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY email DESC");
$data_row = $account;
foreach($a_list as $row){
  $data_row .=  '<option value="'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['email'].'</option>'."\n";
}
echo $data_row;
unset($row);
```

The php code above is for the select element multiclient. I need variable $account to change to 'Client'."\n"; for the client element. Does anyone know how to do this without creating separate load-account.php for each select elemennt? I found it's easy to do if the select elements are located on different pages since I can use `parse_url(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI' , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), PHP_URL_PATH);` to make the distinction. However, in this case, both elements are located on the same page. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: basically an include is just replaced by the imported code. So you can move the `$account` initialisation out of the included file, and place it just before the `include` in the main file. This way you can set a different value each time you include it. (you can put a default value in case not set, it's safer)

Comment: But doesn't doing this require ajax call to pass $account value?

Comment: not if it is directly included like you do. When the PHP is built server side, your file code is directly injected in the main file, it's just like you would replace your `include` line by the file content

Comment: @Kaddath You're a freaking effing genius! Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that accepts an argument that will determine the value of the tag attribute(multiclient or client for your case).

Read more about http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php here

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass the argument selection to php without doing ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you, but your function call should be like loadAccount('MultiClient'); or something

Comment: Sorry, I've limited experience on this so I don't know much about function and its capabilities.  I guess my question was how would php know which select for the code to be executed? If I created loadAccount('MultiClient') in the php, how would php know to execute this function for multiclient?

Comment: That's your function call. Your function definition should be: function loadAccount ($clientType){$account = '<option value="'.$clientType.'" selected disabled hidden>'.$clientType.'</option>'."\n"; //remaining code here}. Again, you should read more about user-defined functions

Answer (score 0):

Create function in load-account.php to achieve what you want.

you can create two functions lets say: multiclient and client, then call the function you want results from

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass the argument selection to php without doing ajax?